# Creating a bare git repository with specific default branch using Jgit

Tags: git, jgit

From Git version 2.28.0, we can create a repository with specific default branch using

`git init --initial-branch=trunk`

I wanted to do the same with Jgit for bare repository but couldn't find the corresponding API either in `Git.java` or `InitCommand.java` .

Is this feature supported in Jgit ?

Thanks.

Comment: You could also just accept the default, then rename it after it’s created.

Comment: To rename a ref, I think we need to have concrete ref present in the repository. But in this case, since its empty repository, we won't have ref for `master`. Only HEAD will be having value `/refs/heads/master`

Comment: I think there is no concept of a default branch for none-bare Git repos. To simulate `--initial-branch` you could just rename `master` to whatever the initial branch should be named. The `RenameCommand` is documented here: http://archive.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.9.0.201710071750-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/RenameBranchCommand.html

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann I missed to mention that my question is in the context of bare git repository.

Comment: After initializing a bare repository, you can just change `HEAD` to point to `refs/heads/trunk`. JGit provides the `RefUpdate` to manipulate refs directly (https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/RefUpdate.java). Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported/implemented by [JGit](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit) at the moment (Q4 2020)

You can see the tests in [`InitCommandTest.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/InitCommandTest.java) using the option `--separate-git-dir`, but none using `--initial-branch`.

Considering a `git init --initial-branch=xxx` does not leave any visible local configuration in the `.git/config` file, this is not a feature easily replicated at the repository creation step.